# How can I output a number based on IF conditionals in different cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am sorry if I made the wrong question, I'm getting started with Google Sheets and wanted to figure out how to work on some kind of score calculator based on IF conditionals. Here is the example:

[image: Example]

It's going to be used on a Form Responses sheet (I don't want to use the Google Form's Quiz option) where I'll need to answer some Y/N questions, in the "Total" column, there is going to be a final score out of 100 based on the "Yes" or "No" answer.

Let's say that the Row # 2 is a submission from a Google Form, and let's say that every submission has by default a score of 100. What the "No" is doing is deducting 10 points from that initial score of 100.

I started with something like =MINUS("100", IF(A2= "No", 10)) but it only works with one cell.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Apologies but I am confused on what is your goal here. Do you want to count the number of `No` in a single row, multiple it by 10 then deduct it to 100?

Comment: @NikkoJ. Thank you for the answer. Let's say that the Row # 2 is a submission from a Google Form, and let's say that every submission has by default a score of 100. What the "No" is doing is deducting 10 points from that initial score of 100. Did I explain myself better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in `E2`:

```
=MINUS(100, COUNTIF(A2:D2, "No") * 10)
```

Output:

[image]

### Update:

If you want to use the column header as reference for deduction points, You can use this Custom Function:

> To write a custom function:
>
> 1. Create or open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> 2. Select the menu item Tools > Script editor.
> 3. Delete any code in the script editor.
> 4. For this case, simply copy and paste the code below into your script editor
> 5. Click Save save.

**Code:**

```
function SCORE(range) {
  var map = range.shift();
  var data = range;
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var tally = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
      if(data[i][j] == "No"){
        tally = tally + map[j];
      }
    }
    result.push([100+tally])
  }
  return result;
}
```

> To call the custom function
>
> 1. Click the cell where you want to use the function.
> 2. Type an equals sign (=) followed by the function name and any input value — for example, =SCORE(A1:D4) — and press Enter.
> 3. The cell will momentarily display Loading..., then return the result.

**Example Usage:**

[image]

*Note: You must always include the column header(deduction points) in your range.*

### Reference:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)
- [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Thank you! This formula works flawlessly, but here is where it gets more complex, what If I want the first "No" to deduct 10 points but the second one to deduct a different amount? like 30 or 5

Comment: @DiegoB - See my updated answer. Also, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)